# getParent returns null in TabActivity

Tags: android, tabactivity

I 'm calling `getParent().setResult(0)` in `TabActivity`. This is called when the user hits previous button. I want the current activity to close and get deleted from the stack.

getparent() returns null. Can someone tell me why does that happen??

```
getParent().setResult(0);
finish();
```

Thanks

**UPDATE:** This is the definition of getParent()...What does embedded child mean. And secondly is the TabActivity an embedded child if it is called from another Activity??

```
public final Activity getParent ()
Return the parent activity if this view is an embedded child.
```

Comment: are you using startActivityForResult()?

Comment: Yes, i m using startactivityforresult to call my activity(tabactivity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't clearly stated you're question. You want to understand how to pass a result back from an Activity to the Activity which called it. You must first understand that Activities aren't hierarchical even though they are kept on a back stack. Later activities do not *belong* to the Activity they are called from.

However, here is the answer the question you meant to ask:

You are using `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)` (Which you can read up on [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities))

When `Activity A` calls `startActivityForResult()` method `Activity B` is started, this should do whatever processing is required and then when it exits either call:

```
setResult(RESULT_OK)
```

when a yes/no is required or

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent)
```

where intent is an `Intent` which contains bundled information you want to use in `Activity A` to act upon.
After `Activity B` exits `Activity A` will resume and call the method:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

This is where you will process the result.

You can read all about this here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to keep this Activity in the history stack do one of the following:

a) when starting the TabActivity in the parent, add flag: FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TabActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

b) OR add android:noHistory="true" in the activity's Manifest like so

```
    <activity
        android:name=".TabActivity"
        android:noHistory="true"
        ...
        >
        ...
    </activity>
```

Then to return the result to the parent and finish TabActivity

```
Intent result = new Intent();
result.putExtra("somevalue", requestCode);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result); // or setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, result);
finish();
```

When you finish(); the TabActivity activity it will not be remembered

Comment: I 'm trying to understand why getParent returns null..any explaination why that is happening.